# How can I add a smiley box in my forum's shoutbox?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm customising [my forum](http://ariane-mascret.loupborgne.com/index.php) (phpbb V3.1.9) so I have installed an extension called "Ajax Shoutbox" (V1.0.4) in a sidebar.
As I wanted to customise it a little more I've search how to add a kind of smiley box under the "send" button where users can clic to add smileys at their shout (like in a standard post) to get something close to that : [shoutbox picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sySnv.jpg).
Currently, if they write it (ie :birthday: or :) ), the shoutbox display it but they have to remember or know each of the 20 smilies.

I've search on internet how to do that but either I've found too old unusable post or they were too complicated for me to understand... (yes, unfortunately I know very few, yet almost nothing about phpbb/html/php ^^')

Currently, the best thing I get is a grey box with nothing in it with this code (plus CSS):

```
    <div id="smiley-box-shout">
        <!-- IF S_SMILIES_ALLOWED and .smiley -->
            <strong>{L_SMILIES}</strong><br />
            <!-- BEGIN smiley -->
                <a href="#" onclick="insert_text('{smiley.A_SMILEY_CODE}', true); return false;"><img src="{smiley.SMILEY_IMG}" width="{smiley.SMILEY_WIDTH}" height="{smiley.SMILEY_HEIGHT}" alt="{smiley.SMILEY_CODE}" title="{smiley.SMILEY_DESC}" /></a>
            <!-- END smiley -->
        <!-- ENDIF -->
        <!-- IF S_SHOW_SMILEY_LINK and S_SMILIES_ALLOWED -->
        <br /><a href="{U_MORE_SMILIES}" onclick="popup(this.href, 750, 350, '_phpbbsmilies'); return false;">{L_MORE_SMILIES}</a>
        <!-- ENDIF -->
</div>
```

Unsurprisingly, it's not working, but I don't know what is missing : htlm code ? php modification ? More ?
Can someone tell me where I'm wrong ?

Thank in advance for the help :]